# Python Marshmallow not detecting error in required field

Tags: python, flask, marshmallow

I am using marshmallow to validate the data of APIs. But, it is not working for required field.

The following code works for length validation.

```
password = fields.String(validate = validate.Length(min=6))
```

But, required field is not working. It just ignore and continue without showing any error on that.

```
password = fields.String(required = True) //not working
```

Comment: We need more context, what did you do to verify the API data?

Comment: I created a schema class using marshmallow and using the schema to validate.
I have data in request.form and i am using schema with load ( schema.load(request.form).errors) where schema is object of my schema class.

Comment: Which version of marshmallow you are using? This may be relevant depending on the version, https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/issues/377

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check this example:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class User(Schema):
    email = fields.Str()
    password = fields.Str(required=True)


User().load({'email': 'abc@gmail.com'}) # raise Exception
User().load({'email': 'abc@gmail.com', 'password': ''}) # Not raise exception
```

Your `request.form` always contain the field `password` but it will be blank.

Comment: so it will detect blank as a given value so does not raise error on that and we have to check for blank data?

Comment: Yes, we have to check for blank data. Check this: https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/quickstart.html#field-validators-as-methods